# Mac OS Extended (Journaled) HDD showing space used, but empty in finder

Tags: finder, hard-drive, disk-utility, hdd

I have a 1 TB Toshiba USB External HDD that I formatted to Mac OS Extened (Case-sensitive, Journaled). (I'm not sure why I did the "case sensitive" part, probably an accident).

When I open the drive in finder it shows as empty (see photo below).
[image: Drive shows as empty in finder]

Yet in disk utility, it shows that 653 GB are used of the total 1 TB.

[image: Here's a screenshot of Disk Utility. Shows 653 GB used.]

Listing the hidden files using terminal shows some hidden things, but nothing huge.

[image: Basically no hidden files taking up space.]

Finally, I ran DiskDrill on the drive (but I think that only detects deleted files/damaged files, but worth a try). Regardless, I only found some 300 GB of data (all of which was random/unnamed).

I'm not sure what to do, and I'm not sure if I'm missing anything obvious. It's been plugged in for well over 3 hours now.

To clarify: I formatted it to Mac OS Extended, added data, and then had this issue. Now I've been scanning it.

- I've tried unmounting/remounting
- I've tried ejecting/remounting

Edit:
[image: entered sudo du command]

Comment: I formatted it then added the data. The drive would be empty if it was formatted now. I've tried unmounting/remounting, restarting, unplugging/replugging.

Comment: Edited the post to add output of sudo du -mc -d /Volumes/Media

Comment: Well, I'm just as lost as you are... I'm not sure what to do...

Comment: Love DaisyDisk but doesn't work for scanning as admin. Gives me "Failed to scan as Administrator". I'll post a screenshot of non-admin scan.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "Sticky bit (t) is set d-wx--x--t and no read bits."?

Comment: The ~650 GB is marked as "hidden space" by DaisyDisk and I can't get the admin scan to work.

Comment: I used "du -d 1 -h /Volumes/Media" and found that it was all in the .Trashes folder. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: @FyrePixel OK, (I was almost right somewhere in the middle of the investigation - wrong command though) please write an answer ;-) and get some reputation points.

Comment: Re DaisyDisk giving you "Failed to scan as Administrator", here is how to fix: 1. Quit DaisyDisk if it's running. 2. Delete the following files:
1) /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.daisydiskapp.DaisyDiskStandAlone.AdminHelper and 2) /Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.daisydiskapp.DaisyDiskStandAlone.AdminHelper   then relaunch DaisyDisk and try again.

Comment: @swa16, this solution to the "Failed to scan as Administrator" error does not work for me. Do you have any other idea?

Comment: Yes, we have seen cases when DaisyDisk's admin helper gets somehow included into the list of disabled services on your system. Please try the following Terminal commands: 

launchctl print-disabled system

It will list the explicitly disable services. Be sure to check the false/true value for com.daisydiskapp.DaisyDiskStandAlone.AdminHelper

To enable a disabled service: 

sudo launchctl enable system/com.daisydiskapp.DaisyDiskStandAlone.AdminHelper

Comment: @swa16 thanks for your help! I have tried this but keep getting the same error. I also used LaunchControl to check that the Helper indeed is loaded (it is), but the error persists. Do you happen to have any other idea what to do...? Many thanks!

Comment: Does the helper now appear enabled in the launchctl list? Try to reboot perhaps. It should work afaik. You can get in touch with support@daisydiskapp.com